# Link to global node modules folder from Angular2 app

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, angular

I wish to have a centralised Node modules folder (using npm update -g to save to C disk) instead of the usual local folder which is contained in the app, due to Angular2 CLI installing 125mb+ worth of Node modules in the local folder.

So in the typescript files we previously imported the angular core like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

But obviously this doesnt work, is it possible to put a prefix or hard URL somewhere to tell the app to search in the global folder for the modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `SystemJs` configuration (usually `systemjs.config.js` file), so it maps `@angular` to you centralized `node_modules\@angular` folder, instead of local one.

```
var  map = {
  'app' : 'app',
  '@angular' : 'C:/node_modules/@angular', // path to centralized repo
};
```

Comment: where will be present this ```systemjs.config.js``` file ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your systemjs.config file should be :

```
 (function(global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things    
    var map = {
        'app':                        'src',         
        '@angular':                   'global location'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },

    //can add as per your requirement
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade',
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });


})(this);
```