# Where will Angular-cli be installed?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Where will Angular-cli be installed?can I run Angular-cli expression without install it globaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is Installed globally

This is a step you only have to do once. Once it's installed globally with "-g", you can skip this step when creating new Angular 2 projects. Also it's important to note, you need Nodejs and NPM installed before you can proceed with this step.

Its is installed in Nodejs Modules Globally

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

a dummy location -> **usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/**

Then use the following Commands to create a new project

```
ng new PROJECT_NAME
cd PROJECT_NAME
ng serve
```

for more info on cli [check the wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki)

Comment: I have multi angular cli projects and each of them has a node module folder.they are similar and I want one node module file for all projects,is it possible?
In other words how to build several angular cli projects with one node module

Comment: Your cli is installed​ in a global node folder where as project has local node module. I dnt think you can use common node modules

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588674/link-to-global-node-modules-folder-from-angular2-app

Please see this link

Comment: Thanks @Ali this was a good learning i dnt know about this thanks

Comment: So see this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480549/install-dependencies-globally-and-locally-using-package-json

Answer (score 0):

[Angular CLI github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

you will use NPM to install angularCLI

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

notice -g parameter it will install cli globally and you can you it in any new project from now on.

CLI is installed in NPM.